# How to ask the other to speak shorter?

Tags: translation, phrase, phrase-request

I talk with a voice assistant 小爱同学.
When I ask it: 今天是几号？
It answers: 今天是9月30号，周四，衣历辛丑年八月二十四。
It is difficult for me to understand this phrase.
I want a shorter answer: 今天是9月30号 or 30号 or 三十.

小爱同学 is very smart. It understands commands in natural language. For example when I say 再说一遍 it repeats its last phrase. The format of the command is not fixed. You can say 刚才您说的那一句我没听清了，麻烦您再说一遍吧 and it will understand you.

I do not know how to ask another (person) to answer shorter. "Can you say it shorter?"

Comment: try 简单点 or 长话短说

Comment: You just need to understand 农历 (which you mistyped as 衣历). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_calendar. Then hopefully you can find the AI's answer quite easy.

Comment: you can say 請長話短說 or 請說重點

Comment: "一句話總結" means summarize into one sentence.

Answer (score 1):

If it is indeed an A.I. machine, you can try issue the command and question together - 給我一個簡短的答覆, 今天是几月几号？ Or, to be polite, add 請 to the front to make it more willing to cooperate :)

Or, try, 簡捷點, 今天是几号？ 或, 簡单的, 今天是星期几？ If it provides the same responses as before, the A.I. wasn't functioning/programmed too good, I would consider 開除她 :)

Comment: 給我一個簡短的答覆, 今天是几月几号？- This phrase is too long. I am not able to pronounce it without mistakes. Is it possible to say the same in a shorter way?

Comment: 小爱 簡單點 今天几号？ 或是 小爱 別囉唆 今天几号？